# If else Update Category echo display image

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, limits

HI

I Need to display an image when Category Update and that image display upto 3 days

i use this but not work

```
 $todaytime = time();
                $timestamp = $show_wallpaper['timestamp'];
                $timediffirence = "360000";
                $minus = $todaytime - $timestamp;


 if ($timediffirence > $minus) {
          $new = "<img src='$siteurl/images/new.gif' />";

       } else {
          $new = "";

        }
```

database info

```
      $sql = "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM wallpaper WHERE categoryid = $catid order by wallpaperid desc LIMIT $from,$max_results";
```

so help me to fix it 
I do like this

IF Category Update then display this image for 3 days else remove image
 this is my task
reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, `$timediffirence` is a number, it does not therefore need to be in double quotes, try this first:

```
$timediffirence = 360000;
```

**Secondly**, 360000 is not 3 days in seconds, it should be

((60 * 60) * 24) * 3 = 259200

**Finally**, try debugging by printing out the values of `$minus` and comparing it with `$timediffirence`